# Xcode4 breakpoints adapt to code changes?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, breakpoints

I have a series of logging breakpoints in Xcode4 that I'm using to selectively log things as I need them. However, whenever I make changes to the code involving adding or deleting lines, these breakpoints get out of sync with where they are supposed to be, sometimes even going to a completely different function.

Is there a way to keep the breakpoint in sync with the code, rather than just rely on the line number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it should, at least it's the IDE's usual behaviour.

Just a thought. Have you tried to reinstall XCode? I have experienced all sorts of weird bugs since the upgrade to XCode 4. For example, being unable to select a XIB file for a popup window in a project---and when creating a project from scratch, I was able to select that XIB and create the popup. At the time I posted a question on StackOverflow about this and it is still unanswered ever since.

Since that time, the project was overhauled and now I build my interfaces from scratch using full Obj-C code, dumping the interface builder 99% of the time...